# Default Users Password Regex

Tags: craft3, users, password, regex

Assume a front end registration form. I would like to validate user passwords before posting to the server. I have not been able to find the default password requirements as of yet for craft 3. Could someone fill in the blank?

From what I have found:

- At least one capital letter
- At least one lowercase letter
- No more than 160 characters

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of existing plugins that look like they might do what you're looking for:

https://plugins.craftcms.com/password-policy

https://plugins.craftcms.com/enforce-password

And of course, you could always write a plugin that meets your exact requirements as well.

Comment: Thanks Brad, this is great information. Perhaps I was unclear, but I was hoping to get a list of what default password requirements craft enforces (So I can pre-inform the user, and include in front-end regex checks)

Comment: The only thing Craft natively enforces is a minimum password length of 6.